# LaTeX-friendly diff tool?

Tags: editors, software

Most visual diff/merge utilities are designed for program code with short lines. They typically do not support line wrapping, and are often not good at highlighting the specific differences between two lines. Instead, they tend to highlight the entire lines. This is obviously a problem for LaTeX, where it is convenient to write paragraphs without line breaks.

Are there any diff tools which are free of these problems and work conveniently with LaTeX? Ideally it would have merge functionality as well.

Note: I am not looking for latexdiff or similar. I am looking for a tool that diffs LaTeX code, not LaTeX output.

Comment: emacs ediff/emerge can highlight differences within a line, although personally I tend to write latex source with auto-wrapping at 75 columns so  that lines are not too long and look better eg when posted to a site such as this, and don't cause churn in source control

Comment: You’ll need a tool that does intra-line diffs, such as `wdiff`  or `xxdiff`. Possibly WinMerge?

Comment: Well, one sentence per line has quite a few advantages in LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

There is a diff tool that is free of these problems and work conveniently with LaTeX. It's called `git diff --word-diff --no-index`. If you want merge functionality as well, you can just setup git for your project (without any remote).

Note: This is not like latexdiff or similar. This tool diffs LaTeX code, not LaTeX output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it bad practice to provide pointers to commercial solutions? Overleaf has a version history tool that shows the diff very nicely IMHO, and that works for long lines too. It does not have a merge function, though.
[image: a simple example of diff across versions as displayed in Overleaf, for a long line]

Comment: It looks like the free Overleaf does give you some access to version history.

Comment: Absolutely! By "commercial" I meant that Overleaf is a company and some LaTeX users may favour free software, 'free' not just in the sense of 'free of charge' ("free" as in "free beer") but in the sense of 'maintained by a community effort' ("free" as in "free speech" :: 'libre').
Thank you for the clarification!